# Trying to parse source IP's from apache access log and write the output to a file but only 1 ip is written

Tags: python, apache, parsing

I'm trying to read an apache access log and pull all source ip's from there to an output file.
I'm new to python so i'm not sure i'm doing it right, but it has to be in python.

```
#! python
for line in open('/var/log/apache2/access.log'):
        ip = line.split(' ')[0]
print ip
```

I know that at the moment it's printing to the screen rather than to a file but first i'm trying to get the first part of the script to work.
When i'm running the script it only prints out the first occurrence of the the string which means only 1 ip, I thought that running it with for loop will go through each line of the file but i guess it doesn't work as i wrote it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed indent:

```
#! python
for line in open('/var/log/apache2/access.log'):
        ip = line.split(' ')[0]
        print ip
```

And to write to file you can use something like this:

```
#! python
f = open("ip.txt", "w")
for line in open('/var/log/apache2/access.log'):
        ip = line.split(' ')[0]
        f.write(ip + '\n')
f.close()
```